# how to retrieve the first and last instance of a row in pdo dataset

Tags: php, arrays

I have a dataset that I retrieve using PDO and fetchall. I need to find the first date a part was sold and its cost then also I need to find the last date that part was sold and its cost. I believe I have the php code how I want it because it is returning all the data I need. The question I have then is, how can/should I get the first instance of the row with the date/cost and then the last instance of the row with the date/cost? For example, the part number below, 80049 has 6 rows in my dataset. each with a different sale date and cost. I can easily get the cost/date of the first row but in my code below it's printing out every date/cost instead of the last one. I know why it's doing that with my code so my question is how can I fix that behavior?

The end goal is for the layout to look something like:

Part: Description: First Sold: Cost: Last Sold: Cost:

80049 blah blah    2022-04-20  0.755 2022-04-25 0.755

php with table code:

```
$current_part = "";

$data = $sql->fetchall((PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
echo "<table id='main'>
<tr>
    <th>Part</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Earliest Date</th>
    <th>Earliest Cost</th>
    <th>Last Date</th>
    <th>Last Cost</th>
</tr>";
foreach ($data as $row){
  if ($current_part != $row['part']){
     $current_part = $row['part'];
    echo "
          <tr>
            <td>";echo $current_part;echo"</td>
            <td>";echo $row['description'];echo"</td>
            <td>";echo $row['date_received'];echo"</td>
            <td>";echo $row['cost'];echo"</td>";
} else {
echo      "
             <td>";echo $row['date_received'];echo"</td>
             <td>";echo $row['cost'];echo"</td>
          </tr>";
 }
}
 echo "</table>";
```

[image: Output]

[image: Example Records]

Comment: `<table id='main'>` should be outside the `foreach`. Only build the rows, `<tr>` not tables.

Comment: @user3783243 I tried your suggestion and it got my output to look much better. I edited the question for the issue I am facing now.

Comment: fetchall() gives you a regular PHP array. there is no more PDO or database. from this moment you're working with arrays

Comment: Get rid of the `;echo` and concatenate.  e.g. instead of `<td>";echo $current_part;echo"` do `<td>" . $current_part . "` The new issue is that sometimes you only populate 2 of the 5 columns? Please update code of question as well.

Comment: @user3783243 updated code. My question now, is how can I only print out the first date/cost and the last date/cost? If you look at the screen shot, it shows part, description, first date, first cost, and then it prints the next date/cost until the end of the row and then prints the remaining date/cost on new rows. I know why the code is doing that (bc I'm printing it that way), but I would like to only print the first date/cost and the last date/cost. I hope that made sense

Comment: Can you add example records to the question; or create a db-fiddle?

Comment: You basically want the same thing, a classic _control break_ does. Your data needs to be appropriately sorted to begin with (here, by product first, and by date ascending second.) Then you simply compare the current product to that of the previous iteration. If they differ, you encountered the first record for a product. In that case, output the value from the previous record first, if that exists (that would be the _last_ record for the previous product then), and then that from the current one (which will be the first record, for the current product.)

Comment: And after the loop, you still need to output the very last record - because for that, no change to any "following" product will occur any more. But you only need to output that one, if you did not already output it as the _first_ record for the last product.

Comment: @CBroe should I still use a foreach loop for this?

Comment: @user3783243 I have attached a screenshot from the database with a sample of some records.

Comment: @SkylarP I can't work with that data. Look at `min`, `max`, and `group by` functions in mysql.

Comment: @user3783243 I was able to retrieve my desired results by altering my sql query with the above functions. Though it wasn't mySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually to change the pervasive query I was using. This was the query I was using to begin with:

```
select part,cost,description,date_received,qty_received
from v_po_history 
where part not like '*%' and date_received >= '2022-04-01' and date_received <= '2022-04-30' and location = 'HS' 
order by part, date_received asc
```

And the answer:

```
select part,min(cost) as Lowest_Cost,max(cost) as Highest_Cost, min(date_received) as First_date, max(date_received) as Last_Date, description, (max(cost) - min(cost)) as Difference
from v_po_history 
where part not like '*%' and date_received >= '2022-04-01' and date_received <= '2022-04-30' and location = 'HS'
group by part,description
```